# how to move from listview item to other layout in android

Tags: android

how to move from listview item to other layout in android .......

am trying to move from listview to other layout by click on it help me plz

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv1;

    private String lv_arr[] = {"Android", "iPhone", "BlackBerry", "Nokia"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle x)
    {
        super.onCreate(x);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
        //lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want something like user will have to option whether he want view data in list form or in grid form right?

Comment: by changing layout you mean changing the activity right? use setOnItemClickListener . . .

Answer (score 0):

Use onItemClickListener for this.
It's simple. if you search around you will get this.

```
 List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondClass.class);
            intent.putExtra("passsomething","value_of_variable");
    startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondActivity.class);
        //  if you just want to navigate to second activity remove the below lines
        //String value = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //i.putExtra("key",value);
        startActivity(i); 
});
```

In SecondActivity

Have a textview if you want to display item clicked in listview in second activity else ignore the below

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null)
{
     String value = extras.getString("key");
     // textview.setText(value);
}
```